# How to input a text file to the Python input() command in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: python, input, text-files, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I have a Python Application Solution. I want to feed a text file to Python's input() command so I don't have to type 25 lines of input when debugging. Is there a way to set the default of the solution so it automatically reads in a text file when looking for input()? If not is there any way to accomplish something similar as a work-around?

I need to use input() specifically because my code is automatically graded. So, I do not have access to a filepath to read in input with other methods, like fileinput, when my code is being graded. What I'm looking for, I suspect, is some sort of setting in Visual Studio, if it exists.

I am not very familiar with Visual Studio, so any extra detail is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider *not* using `input`, and instead using the normal stuff for reading from a file? If you don't know what that is, did you consider putting, for example, `python read file`, `python how to read a file`, or even `how do I read a file in Python?` into a search engine?

Comment: That's the right answer.  Use `sys.stdin.readline()` or the `fileinput` module to do your input.  Production applications almost never use `input`.  I'm surprised how much it comes up here.

Comment: @TimRoberts it comes up because tutorials insist on approaching the language via simple interactive command-line programs and building to more complex ones - rather than starting with *the interactive prompt*, and then moving to simple programs that don't require input, and then showing file I/O.

Comment: Anyway: you can also find the `fileinput` module - the desired workaround, rather than doing it properly - by trying something like `python input from file` in a search engine. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: The reason I'm using input(), as opposed to reading in a file or using fileinput, is because I am in college and my program goes through automatic grading that uses input(). So when it is being graded, my code has to read stuff in with input(), as there is no file to read from. I would like to test my code using input(), but reading in a text file so I don't have to type things over and over or change the method of reading in the test cases before submitting my assignment. I believe there is a way to do this with VS C++ solutions, but I don't know about Python.

Comment: Like in C++ I would use something like freopen_s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = input("Enter a File Here:   ")
with open(file, "r") as f:
    lines = ""
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines = lines + line
print(lines)
```

One of Python's best attributes is its ability to easily modify files. There are a million articles and tutorials online, so you can quickly research what all of this means. For the sake of your problem, this should do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not exactly what I'm looking for, as I would just like to pipe a text file to input() through a Visual Studio setting instead of by reading in the file in my code, so my code is perfectly reusable when I enter it into my school's autograder that uses input(). I tried to clarify what I mean above; sorry for the confusion.